# Download UNIX python wheel in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unix, download

I want to download a UNIX python wheel into my windows PC, for later install it in a UNIX server with no access to the internet

I tried

```
python -m pip download --only-binary :all: --no-cache imbalanced_learn
```

But I get the wheels ***win_amd***, but I need ***manylinux***

Example download in windows:

[image]

```
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
  Saved c:\users\c58210a\onedrive - experian services corp\documents\proyectos\migracion db\descargar librerias\test\imbalanced_learn2\threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Downloading scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (34.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 34.1 MB 6.8 MB/s
  Saved c:\users\c58210a\onedrive - experian services corp\documents\proyectos\migracion db\descargar librerias\test\imbalanced_learn2\scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting scikit-learn>=1.0.1
  Downloading scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (7.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.1 MB 6.1 kB/s
  Saved c:\users\c58210a\onedrive - experian services corp\documents\proyectos\migracion db\descargar librerias\test\imbalanced_learn2\scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 306 kB 242 kB/s
  Saved c:\users\c58210a\onedrive - experian services corp\documents\proyectos\migracion db\descargar librerias\test\imbalanced_learn2\joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.14.6
  Downloading numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.0 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Saved c:\users\c58210a\onedrive - experian services corp\documents\proyectos\migracion db\descargar librerias\test\imbalanced_learn2\numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Successfully downloaded imbalanced-learn threadpoolctl scipy scikit-learn joblib numpy
```

Example download in UNIX:

[image]

```
Collecting imbalanced_learn
  Downloading imbalanced_learn-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (199 kB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/imbalanced_learn-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.14.6
  Downloading numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn>=1.0.1
  Downloading scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Downloading scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (38.1 MB)
  Saved ./s3:/experian-s3-ascend-colombia-internal-buro-data/TempJC/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
Successfully downloaded imbalanced-learn numpy joblib scikit-learn threadpoolctl scipy
```

Regards

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy&paste the output to your question *as text* and format it as a code block. see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10622916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`--platform`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/#cmdoption-platform) ?
On my Ubuntu x86_64 :

```
$ pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform win_amd64 imbalanced_learn
[...]
Saved ./imbalanced_learn-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Saved ./joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved ./numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Saved ./scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Saved ./scipy-1.8.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Saved ./threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
[...]

$ pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 imbalanced_learn
[...]
Saved ./imbalanced_learn-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Saved ./joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved ./numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Saved ./scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Saved ./scipy-1.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Saved ./threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
[...]
```

Or use another version for [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).